# What does `netstat -y` on Windows do?

Tags: netstat

From the help page of Windows netstat, I got this:

> -y            Displays the TCP connection template for all
> connections.
> Cannot be combined with the other options.

Google results are all same sentence from the help page. Does anyone know what is the meaning of "TCP connection template" here? The results with this option have a new field called Template, but the only values observed is "Internet" and "Not Applicable" only.

Answer (score 2):

TCP templates are a new features of Windows Server 2019, Windows 11 and latest revisions of Windows 10.

Different templates are used to select different TCP properties, as the congestion alg, based on the connection latency / RTT. From [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/tcp-templates-for-windows-server-2019-8211-how-to-tune-your/ba-p/339795):

> The Internet template is used for connections with an RTT of more than
> 10 ms and the Datacenter template is used for connections with an RTT
> of 10 ms or less. Remember that Automatic template that I said you
> don’t need to worry about? Well you still don’t need to worry about
> it. But, just for information sake the Automatic template is taking
> the initial RTT as measured by the TCP connection handshake and
> applying the appropriate template to the TCP connection.
> What’s the difference between the two? The Datacenter template is designed
> for low-latency LAN environments and the Internet template is designed for
> higher latency WAN environments.

For more information about what can be tuned, you can use [Get-NetTCPSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpsetting?view=windowsserver2022-ps&viewFallbackFrom=win10-ps) and [Set-NetTCPSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-nettcpsetting?view=windowsserver2022-ps&viewFallbackFrom=win10-ps)